# Spring/Hiberate: not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: json, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, orm

I was making a new row entry in the `log` table which contains a foreign key `user_id` that references the parent table `user`. But I get an error saying `not-null property references a null or transient value : edu.psu.sunlabbackend.model.Log.userID`. I assumed the error meant that the parent object did not exist, so I made sure that it existed but I still get the same error. Now I assume maybe it's a problem with the way I am setting up the foreign key, so I have tried all sort of stuff like uni/bidirectional mapping, cascading, fetching eager/lazy. I also let JPA Buddy map it for me, and I still get the same issue. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Here is how I was trying to make  POST request and my model classes:

```
{
    "user_id": {
        "id": 97677572,
        "name": "Joe Smith",
        "role": "STUDENT",
        "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
    "location": "OUT",
    "time": "2023-12-27T14:30:00Z"
}
```

User.java

```java
@Entity(name="user")
@Table(name="user")
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "name", "role", "status"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class User  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long ID;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "status")
    private Status status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userID", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Log> logs = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

Log.java

```java
@Entity(name="log")
@Table(name="log")
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "time", "location"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Log {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "time")
    private Timestamp Time;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User userID;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "location")
    private Location location;

}
```

UserRepository.java

```java
public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM user " +
        "WHERE (LOWER(user.name) LIKE CONCAT('%', :name, '%') OR :name IS NULL) " +
        "AND (id = :id OR :id IS NULL) " +
        "AND (role = :role OR :role IS NULL) " +
        "AND (status = :status OR :status IS NULL)"
        , nativeQuery = true)
    List<User> searchUsers(String name, Long id, String role, String status);

}
```

Comment: Can you include the part of the code where you are trying to save the Log object?